# Google Adwords with Angular 5

Tags: angular, single-page-application, google-ads-api

I'm trying to use AdWords in a checkout SPA built with Angular 5. I need to set variables such as "google_conversion_value" and then run the script located at //www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js

However there are 3 issues:

1. I can't use what the documentation says as this is an SPA.
2. Setting the variables then injecting the script causes the values to be null upon the script being injected
3. Alternatively, injecting the script FIRST then setting the values with a promise is making it fire before they are set.

2:

```
let googleAdWords = this.marketingService.googleAdWords();
if (googleAdWords != undefined) {
 window.google_conversion_language = googleAdWords.google_conversion_language;
 window.google_conversion_format = googleAdWords.google_conversion_format;
 window.google_conversion_label = googleAdWords.google_conversion_label;
 window.google_conversion_value = googleAdWords.google_conversion_value;
 window.google_conversion_currency = googleAdWords.google_conversion_currency;
}
this.marketingService.loadScript('//www.googleadservices.com/pagead   /conversion.js')
```

3:

```
this.marketingService.loadScript('//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js').then(() => {
 this.zone.run(() => {
  let googleAdWords = this.marketingService.googleAdWords();
  if (googleAdWords != undefined) {
   window.google_conversion_language = googleAdWords.google_conversion_language;
   window.google_conversion_format = googleAdWords.google_conversion_format;
   window.google_conversion_label = googleAdWords.google_conversion_label;
   window.google_conversion_value = googleAdWords.google_conversion_value;
   window.google_conversion_currency = googleAdWords.google_conversion_currency;
  }
 });
});
```

--loadscript in service--

```
loadScript(scriptUrl: string) {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
  scriptElement.src = scriptUrl;
  scriptElement.onload = resolve;
  document.body.appendChild(scriptElement);
 });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure you're already solved this but in case somebody needs it, here is what worked for me.

**STEP 1**

Put this in your index.html, replacing XXXXXXXXXXX with your own actual conversion id.

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Ads: XXXXXXXXXXX -->
script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-XXXXXXXXXX"> 
</script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'AW-XXXXXXXXXXX');
</script>
```

**STEP 2**

Then in your checkout flow, where you want to register the transaction:

```
const gtag = window['gtag'];
gtag('event', 'conversion', {
  'send_to': 'AW-XXXXXXXXXX/CONVERSION_CODE',
  'value': GRAND_TOTAL,
  'currency': CURRENCY,
  'transaction_id': TRANSACTION_ID
});
```

Remember to fill in `AW-XXXXXXXXXX/CONVERSION_CODE`, `GRAND_TOTAL`, `CURRENCY` & `TRANSACTION_ID` with appropriate values.  The above code is **typescript**.

Comment: The question was about using conversion.js, not using gtag.  In some cases (like mine), using google tag manager is not an option.